# Как отсортировать базу данных

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

Возможно ли отсортировать базу данных сразу по нескольким параметрам? Если да, то как? Мой код компилятор не принимает.

Мой код для сортировки:

```
 String selectQuery = "SELECT  date FROM " + TABLE_DATES + " WHERE " + KEY_ID + " = " + id+", WHERE month = "+my;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"SELECT  date FROM " + TABLE_DATES + " WHERE " + KEY_ID + " = " + id+" and month = '"+my+"'"`

Нужно использовать оператор `and`.

Comment: Хорошо, я исправила, но теперь у меня появляется ошибка  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ",": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT  date FROM tableDates WHERE id = 1 and month = September, 2021

Comment: Нужно взять строку в одиночные кавычки. `SELECT date FROM tableDates WHERE id = 1 and month = 'September, 2021'`.

Comment: Тогда все работает, но мне нужно сравнивать с переменной, а не с готовой строкой

Comment: Добавить одиночные ковычки в код создающий селект?

Comment: Вот так? and month = "+' '+my. Тоже не работает

Comment: Я поправил мой ответ.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130092/discussion-between--and-talex).